# What complexity is that a nested loop but the inner loop starts from i and ends with half?

Tags: algorithm

```
for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
   for ( j = i; j >= 1; j = j / 2) {
     // some code
   }
}
```

Assume that the code of the inner loop is constant. I thought its *O(n^2)*
Here is my opinion regarding this question.
I think that the run time of the inner loop is **logi+1** so I got the formula: (log1+1)+(log2+1)+...+(logn+1) then get O(n^2)

but I saw another solution for this is **logi** and then the answer is **O(nlogn)**

then I get confused about which one is correct?
I think that I'm correct but I'm not sure.
So if I'm wrong plz convince me why the second is correct?
I know that the difference between these two is the number of times the inner loop executes

Comment: Please write out your solution with full explanation, and include it in the question as text instead of as a linked image (which is difficult or impossible for some people to read).  I see a bunch of lists of numbers but no explanation as to what you think they represent.

Comment: The second is correct because the MAXIMUM number of times that the inner loop executes for a given `i` is `O(log(n))`.  And therefore `n` of them cannot exceed `O(n log(n))`.  I can't figure out what misunderstanding lead you to try to add up running times of the inner loop for each possible `i`.

Comment: Expanding on Nate Eldredge's comment, see "[Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527)".

Comment: @NateEldredge Oh! I'm sorry for the linked image, now I've edited my post

Comment: @btilly because when I list i = 1 I get the run time of the inner loop is 1 and i = 2 is 2 and so on... then I think the run time is logi+1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner loop has the time complexity of O(log(i)), and the outer loop has the time complexity of O(n). The overall time complexity is O(nlog(n)).

We can also get the time complexity with your calculation:

`(log1 + 1) + (log2 + 1) + ... + (logn + 1)` <= `(logn + 1) + (logn + 1) + ... + (logn + 1)` = `n * log(n) + n` = `O(nlog(n))`. We can discard `n` because `nlog(n)` is the dominating in the polynomial `n * log(n) + n`. The calculated time complexity is O(nlog(n)) as well.

Comment: I can understand your explanation and I probably know where I'm wrong I can't add each logi+1 together and then expand to get the 1+2+2+3+3+...

Comment: And I want to know why this is wrong. why can't do it? Could you please tell me why

Comment: You can, of course, expand to get 1+2+2+3+3+...+(logn + 1). There are `n` items in this calculation, and all of them are equal or less than `logn + 1`. The sum is less than `n * (logn + 1)`, not `n * n`.

Comment: Oh! I see, after expanding the series it seems to have the pretty law that is (1*2^0)+(2^2^1)+...
It can't promise that the last item also has this regular, however.
Thanks!